# Tutorial on JPA mapping file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, mapping

Is there a great tutorial on how to use JPA mapping file?  Accompanying related source code for the mapping file would be great also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Simple Tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernateannotations/hibernate-annotations-tutorial.shtml)

[A bit more in depth Tutorial](http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/JPA+Tutorial+1+-+Getting+Started)

Comment: Second link is broken.  Link: http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/JPA+Tutorial+1+-+Getting+Started

Answer (score 0):

There is also a good doc. on the different entity configurations here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html_single/#configuration